# How to copy maven dependency list from Eclipse as text

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In Eclipse, when I open my pom.xml file and go to the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab, it shows two windows: Dependency Hierarchy and Resolved Dependencies.

Is there a way to copy/paste or export the list of dependencies shown in the Resolved Dependencies window into a text file, or a way to have maven print out an equivalent list on the command line?

Background: our team has been told we need to provide a list of all our dependencies and their versions, and it'd be a lot faster if there's a way to easily get a textual list of them vs having to manually type out each dependency and its version one by one into a spreadsheet. We have a lot of services and they all have a ton of dependencies when you need to list out the entire dependency tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=<path_to_file>` to get dependencies in a file.

Comment: If you want the full list similar to what eclipse shows, add the verbose flag `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -DoutputFile=<path_to_file>`. It's very helpful when you want to search for "omitted for conflict" to check the versions of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than just a list, but if you generate a [Site](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) it's all nicely documented. Just run

```
mvn site:site
```

inside the directory of your POM. You'll find the Site under target/site.

---

Little suggestion:

If your company wants to track the dependencies of applications, you shouldn't rely on lists or the like. Have a look into things like the [dependency-check-maven](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html) plugin to scan for vulnerabilities during development and [SBOM](https://www.nist.gov/itl/executive-order-14028-improving-nations-cybersecurity/software-security-supply-chains-software-1) to track dependencies later.

Comment: Oh, we do have automatic dependency tracking, but someone just really wants it in a Sharepoint list too.